# rookie questions : code structure ,writing my own admin/auth/registration from scratch , global functions and variables

Tags: python, django

I'm a LAMP developer and i've just started learning/writing code in python/django ... i like it so far but i have problem with couple of pre-built in apps/components and i like to write them from scratch on my own .

most notably admin section AND authentication/registration

i have lots of reason for that but mostly because my native language is not english and the END USER doesn't speak any.i dont like the way admin looks and represents the data , i like to use ajax for most of my forms , i need lots of extra functionality in admin which django doesn't offer out of box and i don't like to hack into it and ...

so with that in mind i'm going to ask my questions

***1*** - how should i structure my admin section ?

admin section basically has the same apps as the user section but with different functions so ,

should i add those functions in the same view as user functions ?
can i make like 2 views in a app ! or a sub directory containing admin view in each app ?

or create a directory in the root and copy all the apps there for admin ? ( the last resort would be split them in 2 different websites with the same app and put them in 2 host on the same server )

basically 2 websites  (1 for admins / 1 for users)  using 1 database

***2*** - auth/registration ,  i want to write my own code for handling these mostly becuz i dont want my admins  and users to be stored in the same table(in database) also they have different columns and different data needs to be stored on registration

i've seen django contrib.auth in action it seems nice and easy , but can i easily modify it to have 2 different sets of login/register form working with 2 different tables?

*if not i have to write my own code , so i have this sub-questions ( i like to know answer to these anyway)*

***2-1*** i need to check if users is logged and if so read it from database on every view , how can i make a function run before every other functions in any view ?

something like

```
from .models import user
def currentUser(request):
 thisUser = user.objects.get(id= request.session.get('user_id') )
```

can i run `currentUser` function on every reques and make `thisUser` available like a global variable to every other function/variable ( i guess i can somehow attach it to `request` which is passed on to every other functions in views ) or should i switch to use classes for views and solve this by inheritance/constructor function

***2-2*** the basic mechanic of authentication on other technologies (im a LAMP developer) is to store logged user id in a session and in each httprequest check that session to see if contains user id if so he/she is logged and would be red from database and if not user is not logged  ... is there anything different in python/django that i should know or it's the same here ?

***2-3*** if i create 2 different app that work with the same table(database) for example `auth` app for registration and login , `user` app for editing user information and other stuff

what is the right/preferred way to create models ? should i define them in 1 app like `user` app

user/models.py

```
class user(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and include them on the auth views ?

auth/views.py

```
from .models import user
def login():
 loggedUser = user.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
```

if so does `auth`app needs a model at all ?

Comment: Just use the built in django facilities and concentrate on your domain logic.

Comment: @RobertMoskal well as i said the end user can't speak/read english .. and i like to learn by writing code .

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of Django admin plugins that exist. Some might do everything you need or only require minor modification. If you still want to write your own from scratch I suggest you study a few of them to get ideas. Check out [this page](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/admin-interface/) for a good list.

As for the specific things you want to accomplish those are more specific questions than "what is best" format. I suggest you try to implement it and open a new question when you run into trouble.

I will help you with the first question by saying I have never been a fan of two sites for frontend/admin and even Django admin agrees by name spacing everything under the url /admin so routes don't collide.

Also the second, use the Django auth and simply extend it to do what you want. It ties into a lot more than you think. Admin/user accounts in the same table is not inherently a risk, separating actually requires more code which is where risk is introduced.

The last thing you want to do when adopting a framework is to immediately start throwing away huge parts of it. Try to get it to do what you want, then customize. I am sure you will find the framework to be malleable to your needs.